# How can we depend on the mathematical axioms that break down at the nano-level?

Tags: models, approximations

Mathematics "makes sense" at our scope of view. For example, gravity seems to obey the fact that it accelerates at a rate of 9.8 meters a second^2. However, when an object drops, the force of gravity is too weak to overcome the electrostatic force - so it never reaches 0.

Could we say then, we "discover physics"? We describe certain equations for the physical phenomena that is happening? Couloub discovered his equations that led to the above conclusion.

Also, why don't we see a bright sky at "night"? Because of physics (universe expansion, etc).

My question is, how can we depend on mathematics 100% in physics if it leads to obstacles like these? Instead, if we took it with a large grain of salt, it could work.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21051/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Jossie, the question is fairly broad. I'm closing it _as a duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematics is just a systematic way of stating facts about the world.  It is only useful inasmuch as it is internally self-consistent.  The latter fact means that there is nothing to "assume" about mathematics.  It is a relationship between axioms and conclusions that enables one to succinctly summarize many observations.

Something like Galileo's gravitational experiments in Pisa is necessarily logically prior to a conclusion like "in the absence of air resistance, all objects near to the surface of earth will accelerate downward with an acceleration of $9.8\,\,{\rm m/s^{2}}$."  All the latter statement does is summarize the experiments.  And all mathematics gets you is having the power of having that summary turn into an assumption for a later experiment, which can then be checked against other things.

In the end, you could, in principle, do physics without mathematics.  It would just be infinitely harder to understand any of it.  Mathematics is just a language that we can use to focus our thinking.

Comment: 'The latter fact means that there is nothing to "assume" about mathematics. It is a relationship between axioms and conclusions'  Well, we would need to assume the axioms then, wouldn't we?

Comment: @Him, sure but you're always free to choose another set of axioms, and work out what the new conclusions would be.  There's no rule that you have to choose one axiom set a priori.  In physics, ultimately, the thing that sorts it out is simply observation, right?

Comment: "the thing that sorts it out is simply observation."  I'm unaware of any experiments to verify that, say, there exists a successor to the number 978176519074.  This is simply taken for granted in first-order Peano arithmetic, and physicists just roll with it, AFAIK.  It seems that there were some experiments in the 1800s to verify the parallel postulate.  I'm not aware of experiments to verify axioms of ZF, or even other axioms of Geometry.  "All right angles are equal to each other"... are you aware of any experiments to verify this?